# How disable azure-time-trigger-function based on condition

Tags: azure-functions

I have azure time trigger function written, which cleans up the azure storage blobs which are older than 14 days. Now, i would like parameterize the number of days and also wants disable the service if the value is '-1' so that no cleanup will happen.

How can I do this at service level?

Comment: Don't modify the trigger. That is the wrong approach. What you need to do is have your conditional logic inside of the function

Comment: No you cannot modify the trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want to parameterize the number of days and get the days value from Application settings.

You could just set the key value in the Application settings, and then get it with `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("key")`.

[image]

[image]

> wants disable the service if the value is '-1' so that no cleanup will happen.

This should not be a problem, you don't need to disable the timertrigger function, just in your method do a value judgement to confirm if clean the blob.

Comment: Thank you George Chen for your response. We have implemented the same way right now.